# After .load, html() changes but disappears in moment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this problem with my code, I dynamically load modal content from external file, but when i try to change html of div inside that file after load it appears for a quick moment and disappears, would anyone have any idea why? Cheers

Code here:

**External modal content**

```
<div class='modal-dialog' role='document'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
        <form role='form' action='controlPanel' class='form-horizontal' method='POST'  enctype='multipart/form-data' style='margin-left: 1%;'>
        <div class='modal-header'>
            <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class='modal_title' id='modal-title'>Delete user(s)</h4>
        </div>
        <div class='modal-body'>
            <h5>Please confirm that you want to delete following users:<br/></h5>
            <div id="modal-data">

            </div>
            <span class="text-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation" aria-hidden="true"></i> After deleted user accounts can't be restored.</span>
        </div>
        <div class='modal-footer'>
            <input type='submit' id='formSubmit' class='btn btn-primary' value='Delete' name='newUser' onclick='checkForm(7, event);'>
            <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS function**

```
function delete_user(){
        var users = "";
        $("input[id^='rowInput']").each(function(){
            if($(this).prop("checked") == true)
            {           
                users = users + $(this).data('name') + "<br/>";
            }
        });
        update_modal("controlPanel", "delete-user");
        $("#modal-data").html(users);
        show_modal();
}
function update_modal(page, url){
    $('#modal').load('../templates/'+page+'/modals/'+url+'.php');
}
function show_modal(){
    $('#modal').modal('show');
}
```

Comment: I'm guess you have a `<div id="modal">` wrapping all of the above html, and since you call `update_modal()` as part of `delete_users`, you're running into a race condition. delete_user does whatever it has to, and them promptly get overwritten by `update_modal()` doing its thing a split second later.

Comment: So would you think solution would be introducing a delay?

Comment: no. what if there's a net.burp and the load is delayed? e.g. you delay 0.5 seconds, but the burp takes 0.6 seconds to resolve? better solution is to revamp your updates so you're not updating a parent node after updating the child.